# Find $f(x)$ to which the given sequence of functions converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

$$f_{n}(x) = \begin{cases} \sin^{2}\pi x, & n≤ |x|≤n+1, \\
  0,& |x| < n \text{ or }|x|≥ n+1.\end{cases}$$

How can I find $f(x)$ to which $f_{n}(x)$ converges?
I do always have problems with finding $f(x)$ for the sequence of functions given in the form of $n$. Is there any particular way to find $f(x)$ for such functions$?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x\in\Bbb R$, $f_n(x)=0$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ with, at most, one exception. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$.

And the convergence is not uniform, since you have$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):f_n\left(n+\frac12\right)=1.$$

Comment: Here $f_{n}(x)$ is tending to zero. Can I give the explanation behind it as '' since when $n$ tends to $ \infty$, it is greater than any $x \in R$. So, according to the definition of given function, $f_{n}(x)$ is $0$ for very large $n$".

Comment: I don't think that that makes sense. It is not true that an individual $n\in\Bbb N$ is greater than any $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Then why does $f_{n}(x)$ tend to $0 ?$

Comment: Because each sequence $(f_n(x))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ consists only of $0$'s with, at most, one exception, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Clearly, something in my answer displeased you. What is it?

Comment: No sir, I've got it what you are trying to explain. Thanks.